# Typo3 Error with partial

Tags: validation, typo3, partial, fluid, extbase

I have this action:

```
/**
 * updateForm action
 * 
 * @param \Whmcs\Registration\Domain\Model\User $user
 * @validate $user \Whmcs\Registration\Validation\Validator\ValidateValidator 
 * @return void
 */
public function updateFormAction(\Whmcs\Registration\Domain\Model\User $user)
{
    $dbuser = $this->userRepository->getUserByMail($user->getEMailAddress())[0];
    $this->view->assign('user',$dbuser);
}
```

which uses this view:

```
<f:layout name="default" />
<f:section name="content">
    <legend>Benutzerdetails hinzufuegen</legend>

    <f:render partial="Error" arguments="{object:user}" />

    <f:form action="update" object="{user}" name="user" arguments="{user:user}" additionalAttributes="{role:'form'}">

        ...

    </f:form>
</f:section>
```

When I try to open the page, I only see a blank page. In my apache error.log this line appears:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setParent() on a non-object in /var/www/typo3_src-6.2.x/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Error/Result.php on line 216
```

If i remove

```
<f:render partial="Error" arguments="{object:user}" />
```

from the view, or remove

```
$this->view->assign('user',$dbuser);
```

from the action, the site loads correctly. 
The partial I try to render contains this:

```
<f:form.validationResults for="{object}">
    <f:if condition="{validationResults.flattenedErrors}">
        <div class="alert-box radius alert radius">
            <f:for each="{validationResults.flattenedErrors}" as="errors" key="propertyPath">
                <ul>
                    <f:for each="{errors}" as="error">
                        {error}
                        <br />
                    </f:for>
                </ul>
            </f:for>
        </div>
    </f:if>
</f:form.validationResults>
```

anyone knows this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably this line:

```
$dbuser = $this->userRepository->getUserByMail($user->getEMailAddress())[0];
```

Unless your QuerySettings include "setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE)" you should NEVER treat an extbase-result like an array. To get the first entry from your result, use getFirst(). This way you won't break the storageObject.
Another way would be using toArray().

If you do a "print_r($dbuser);" with your current code, you should even see a warning by extbase.

Comment: Okay thanks, but the problem is, when i assign a user object to the view, typo3 throws the exception. No matter if i get the object from the database or if i set it to Null or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. 
Simply, I forgot to add ' to the view. Thats how my view look now:

```
<f:layout name="default" />
<f:section name="content">
    <legend>Benutzerdetails hinzufuegen</legend>

    <f:render partial="Error" arguments="{object:'user'}" />

    <f:form action="update" object="{user}" name="user" arguments="{user:'user'}" additionalAttributes="{role:'form'}">

        ...

    </f:form>
</f:section>
```